# use of ''Getuserconfirmation" in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

use of ''Getuserconfirmation" in react router v4. What is the use of it, with this and without this difference ?

```
const callbacks = (data) => {
  console.log("callback consoled");
}

const getConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
  console.log('heyyy');
const allowTransition = window.confirm(message)
  callbacks(allowTransition)
}

class App extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return(
        <Router getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation}>
        <div>
            <Link exact to = "/">home</Link>
            <Link to = "/men">men</Link>
            <Link to = "/women">women</Link>
        </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `getUserConfirmation` will be called by router.

The param callback is an react-router inner function, you needn't to define it as like callbacks. it means "next action after confirm" .

The function `getUserConfirmation` must be used with [Prompt](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Prompt) , which has no [when](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt/when-bool) prop.